# pip install matplotlib fails: 'cannot build package freetype; "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1'

Tags: matplotlib, pip, freetype, egg

I want to use matplotlib.pyplot.  I can't because

```
altoidnerd@LEPTON:~/ $ pip install matplotlib
```

is failing on ubuntu 14 giving an egg_info error, and warning "cannot build package freetype"

```
* The following required packages can not be built:

                        * freetype

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-8UvQcW/matplotlib
```

But

```
altoidnerd@LEPTON:~/$ dpkg -L libfreetype6
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6.11.1
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libfreetype6
/usr/share/doc/libfreetype6/FTL.TXT.gz
/usr/share/doc/libfreetype6/ft2faq.html
/usr/share/doc/libfreetype6/TODO
/usr/share/doc/libfreetype6/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libfreetype6/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libfreetype6/pcf
/usr/share/doc/libfreetype6/pcf/README
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6
```

my debug.log is here:  http://pastebin.com/rvDuYDiy

A discussion about this on github was closed last year, but I was unable to use it to solve the problem (I left a note):

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3029

I started a [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/2y89j0/pip_install_fail_command_python_setuppy_egg_info/) too.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I'm having the same one now but `ln -s` was disabled in recent OS's to the core directories.

Answer (score 10):

This did the trick for me:

```
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev pkg-config
```

Answer (score 2):

The following command mentioned in the [github thread](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3029) that you mentioned above works for me:

`sudo ln -s /usr/include/freetype2/ft2build.h /usr/include/`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue solved by:

```
easy_install -U pip

pip install matplotlib
```